# Is it Possible to get user input(multiline message)without a newline

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am taking user input and my message is a multi line string,so whenever i execute my script, a newline is printed.

code:

```
name = "name"
message_count = "count"
curr_time = "curr_time"
input_message = f"""
╔=======-{name}|{message_count}|{curr_time}
|_____
"""    
var = input(input_message)
```

Output:

[image]

i want the cursor to be on same line as the input message,is it possible in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the newline at the end of the string.

```
input_message = f"""
╔=======-{name}|{message_count}|{curr_time}
|_____"""
```